# how to rewrite urls in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URLs look like this: (`Y` is an integer, `X` and `Z` are text)

```
/posts/X/Y-Z
```

I want to rewrite so that it looks like

```
/posts/X/Y
```

-`Z` is always at the end not counting `?` and `#`

I just don't understand the syntax of rewrites at all. I've tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/./([0-9]+)-.$ posts/./$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/posts/(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*)$ /posts/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: I have tried all sorts of combinations and going to http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php but i cant get even a simple rewrite to work

Comment: Have you enabled RewriteEngine? `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Yes rewrites are working - i just don't understand how to write them. Any good links that explain regex would be useful

Comment: You should start with the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/), which includes an [introduction to regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html).

Comment: Thanks that's much better docs than what i was using

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^posts/(\w+)/([0-9]+)-(.+)$ /posts/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```